# Authentication in Firebase using node.js

Tags: firebase

For some reason I can't reply to this topic: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/14bq1rjxnn/firebase-transport-unavailable-while-authenticating-user-with-firebase-email-and-password

I'm having the same problem (not being able to authenticate on Firebase using node.js) and since it was posted this would be available soo, I'd like to ask how is it going and if there's any kind of release date for this feature, as it's essencial for the app we're building, but we still can wait a few months for it.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to authenticate on server side with username pswd?can't you app do it directly from client?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase released v2.1.0 (on Jan 6, 2015) of the Firebase Web / Node.js client which includes support for anonymous auth, email / password auth including user-management methods, and OAuth-token auth  in Node.js.

Check out the changelog at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html.

Comment: This support seems to have been removed in v3. Any details on why? Or is there a plan to reinstate it?